# Is there a way to create a separate favorite list of my own answers?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks, tag-watching

Often times, I tend to refer back to my old answers while tackling a new question.  Is there a way to favorite questions answered by me and view them as a separate list for handy reference?

I know there is the `favorite` feature.  What I am looking for is the ability to have a separate favorite list for questions with my answers.

Comment: It's not really a duplicate.  I do know I can favorite questions.  My issue is to filter the favorites so that I can see only the questions that I have answered.

Comment: Uber-meta dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1569/175248

Comment: Why I am being downvoted?  I feel it is a genuine requirement.  I am not a fan of bookmarks or searching through my general favorites list.

Comment: Upvote anyway. But still, probably because dupe -> ---no--- not enough research effort.

Comment: Consider that currently SE doesn't have that feature, and it had been asked before, you need more convincing reasons to convince SE developers to add the feature.